# Phone restarting nonstop

Tags: boot-loop

My phone started rebooting all by itself all the time after I did 2 things with it. Installed Snapdragon BatteryGuru and put it on learning mode (for an estimated 3 days I guess) so that I could start saving battery by the app learning my behavior, and cleaned RAM with CleanMaster. These were the only changes I've done, I don't remember which was first but soon my phone started rebooting whether I was handling it or not at random intervals.

I've also noticed the phone was hot all the time, the Note 3 runs into some hot period with some frequency but not with that frequency. I've uninstalled both apps and it didn't work, wiped cache and it didn't work. The phone was still rebooting even on safe mode. After I wiped Dalvik with the help of TWRP, I thought the problem went away but when I hit the power button to turn the screen off, the phone rebooted and it will now always reboot when the screen turns off, even if it's just from the phone being inactive. It doesn't boot-loops, it just reboots, then after a random time, can be seconds, can be half an hour, it will reboot again. Note 3 SM-N9003 VJUBMI6.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132790/discussion-on-question-by-thiago-phone-restarting-nonstop).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

This may be a dumb question but have you tried a factory restore?

I had the same issue happen on my HTC Inspire a long time ago.  Even after I uninstalled an app, the random reboots would still happen.  It wasn't until I did a factory restore did the issue finally go away.

Not sure what exactly in the factory restore would have fixed the issue for me, but you may want to give that a shot.

**Solution 2**

Have you uninstalled the Snapdragon BatteryGuru? I know you uninstalled CleanMaster. The battery running hot could be due to BatteryGuru running the phone at MAX (fastest possible processor speed, etc) and causes the overheating.  Internal safeguards then causes the phone to shut down or reboot.

Comment: I'm avoid this like I avoid Satan. I'm by far the heaviest user I personally know, I use like 5000mAh of this phone every single day and I don't even use social networks. Resetting this phone is probably gonna cost me like a full day to leave all the settings customized the way I like them to be. This phone practically reads my thoughts as it is

Comment: Are you rooted? If so, it would not be difficult to back things up and restore everything.

Answer (score 0):

Boot loops can be a hardware issue (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Glllc7bEJs) one). If you did not change your firmware or alternate boot partition and it's looping from the alt partition then it's likely hardware. Changes to Android don't affect the alt partition (recovery) that's why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue could be caused by your power key, If you fixed the issue and the power key causes a crash then you can see by process of elimination that it's caused by either the sleep settings, Deep sleep, CPU power down, etc.. or the actual button itself is getting stuck every so often.   ..

It sounds to me like most likely the BatteryGuru app has changed the method of sleep on your device, this means it uses less power while the screen is off, this causes issues like notifications, messages, calls not being received while the screen is off, because the sleep method is set to totally power off the CPU.. I feel like BatteryGuru has added an unsupported method on your device that's causing a crash on sleep mode.